# Find Bluetooth devices within specific distance

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an android application to find Bluetooth devices within a specific distance. Now, I developed an application to get all nearby Bluetooth devices with their RSSI. now I want to find devices that only being within 2 meters. Actually approximate distance is enough. I read more. but I couldn't find a solution. Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I did tests with some Bluetooth low energy Beacons and the distance calculation is very unreliable.

It is done according to the intensity of the received signal, also in the configuration of the beacon that I used, you can select the emission power (weaker to be detected only at close range) but even so many times it said that the strongest signal came from one farther away.

I think the only thing you can hope is to say that some beacon (or bluetooth device) is close, within a radius of about 10m; but not to say which one is closer or which one is at 2 m or less

Hope it will help.

Comment: Do you know any formula to get distance using RSSI

Comment: I used a library like this https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html I don't know how to do it in any other way. Despite using a library and with all devices identically I never got a reliable distance result.

Comment: I also used this. same result.